# Obtain assembly from executable

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am on a hunt to write a program that will be able to read assembly code from a specified .exe . What i am trying to do is to read the assembly code of a executable, in order to find instructions that i can replace with equivalent instructions, in order to obtain different byte code.

This is generally called a source scrambler / signature scrambler, that modifies assembly code in order to obtain different byte code which results in different signatures.

I was reading about the Assembly class in C# , but did not find anything that could return something like a IEnumerable that contains assembly code from the .exe

Is there anyone that can educate me on this? Is this even possible? Different approaches?

Comment: You say "assembly code" but seems to refer to .NET. Can you clarify what kind of executables you want to decode, does it include non-.NET executables? I ask because .NET executables doesn't contain "assembly code", they contain intermediate language, IL.

Comment: This is possible to do for natively compiled modules. If you just needed one change, then it would probably not be all that hard to look for, say, a two-instruction sequence that could be swapped without affecting the outcome, as long as you have debug symbols or a map file. However, to do this in general you need to do a lot of ground work up front.

Comment: The executable i am trying to decode is an .exe built from my own C++ project. So i believe it is a .Net executable?

Comment: Btw, do anyone reading this know of something like a "equivalent instruction set generator"?. So if i were to input "mov eax, 0", then i want a list of all instruction set equivalent for that instruction, for example is "xor eax, eax" equivalent with "mov eax, 0" :)

Comment: There are hardly any instruction pairs that have the exact same semantics - why would there be? - it would just be wasting space in the instruction encoding that could be used for other, useful instructions. --- Whereas `xor eax, eax` and `mov eax, 0` both set the `eax` register to zero, one alters the flags while the other does not. If the code that follows does not rely on an existing flag state, then it does not matter which one is used, but it requires deep analysis to determine whether that's the case.

Comment: @Weirdrandom I would recommend using Mono.Cecil to extract and modify CIL assembly from your own application. But changing IL opcodes might not necessarily mean the JITed assemebly will be different

Comment: Ah oki ty. I have found a way to generate generate .asm files from my .cpp file, then i can generate an object file (.o) from that assembly file, and with that object file, i can load it into an .exe file. Pretty happy with the progress so far. So between all this, i will basically write a polymorphic engine (very simple) that will just insert junk code in between whatever lines i now decide to operate on. This should generate different signatures for this whole process i am pretty sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET does not really deal with Byte Code. All .NET Programms are turned into somthing called MSIL that is executed by teh .NET Runtime and only then turned into bytecode. The whole process is very similar to how JavaBytecode works.

As a result you get full access to the names of anything. You can even use .NEt Executeables like a .DLL file. But replacing stuff is not easy, outside of inheritance or replacing of the files.

The kind of bitwise manipulation you propably need, requires working with naked pointers. And the .NET Developers went out of their way so you would no ever have to use naked Pointers. You can still use them using Unsface code, but as this sounds like the primary use of your programm you are propably better of starting with something like native C++ instead. Really anything taht uses naked pointers as default, rather then a fallback.

Comment: Oh alright gotcha. Do you have any links or libraries that i can include in a C++ project to read from .exe? If not, what would be your method of approach to read from an executable?

Comment: @Weirdrandom: I got no examples. However it is important to stress this. C++ .NET has the same .NET Limitations that C# has. I talked about Native C++ - the C++ that evolved from C and stil uses naked pointers for everything down to arrays.

Comment: Alright gotcha! I've might found a solution. One thing i might be able to do is to generate an asm.c file which holds the assembly code from my .cpp file. Then i can read from that, and maybe recompile it back into a .cpp ?

Comment: @Weirdrandom Now it seems like you are asking for Decompilation, Automatic Modification and recompilation. This is very advanced. And especially the mdidle part is either "just copy a pre-modified file" easy or "you need a AGI for this" hard. The right people to ask for this would be Hackers and Crackers, but answers in that direction are clearly outside the scope of this Forum.

Comment: Ah oki! Yep that is the realm i am in. I do not believe i will make anything super advanced, just something that modifies it. What i had in mind was to basically have a very simple list of instructions that are equivalent. So when i read a line, and that line exists in on of my positions in my list dictionary, i will fetch out an instruction from the value pair of that key and replace it. Something like this. But ye you are right, this was harder than i thought. I have seen that one can decompile a c++ down to asm through a command line, so that will generate my assembly file atleast